# user.clj and init.clj dont work?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

This is my problem:
I need run some code every time I open a new repl, searching in Google I found that I can use the file `init.clj` or the `user.clj` (with Leiningen)

This is the code I need to run:

```
(set! *print-length* 103)  
(println "hello")
(println *print-length*)
```

These are the results with both of the files:

```
[~/project]$ lein repl
hello    <- this is the println, so the file is excecuted  
103      <- this is the println of *print-length* apparently change  
REPL started; server listening on localhost port 20875  
user=> *print-length*  
nil      <- but the val of *print-length* don't change
```

Is there something I need to do or do I have some error?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(alter-var-root #'*print-length* (constantly 103))` in `~/user.clj` works for me.

As far as I know `set!` doesn't work outside of a `binding`'s dynamic scope.

Comment: you know how to put a function "use" to always use a ns?, I have the line (use '[clojure.contrib.string :exclude [repeat butlast drop partition get reverse take]]) but does not work

Comment: @patz try making a new question :)

Answer (score 4):

lein's init.clj runs in the leiningen process, not in your project process. See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen (search for init.clj)